# How can I display my select option values only if a php variable condition is met?

Tags: php, html

I have 5 variables

```
$first ="first";
$second = "second";
$third = "third";
$fourth = "fourth";
$fifth = "fifth";
```

and i have this select option in html

```
    <select name="e1" id="year" class="form-control" required="required">
      <option value="" selected="selected" style="background: #0356e8;color: white;">-  -</option>
      <option value="Attend To" style="background: #fd0303;color: white;">Attend To</option>
      <option value="Explore" style="background: #fd7803; color: white;">Explore</option> 
      <option value="Prompt" style="background: #fdd303; color: white;">Prompt</option>
      <option value="Unaided" style="background: #58d95e; color: white;">Unaided</option>
      <option value="Mastered" style="background: #12c4f9; color: white;">Mastered</option> 
      <option value="Not Applicable" style="background: grey; color: black;">Not Applicable</option>
    </select>
```

How can i make it in a way that if `$first ="first"` then the first option should not display `<option value="Attend To" style="background: #fd0303;color: white;">Attend To</option>`... this should not display.

if `$second = "second";` then first and second option should not display...

likewise for third and fourth.

Comment: You can add an IF statement and if the condition is true, you can add style="display:none" so that it won't be visible

Comment: Okay.... will try that...

Comment: why don't use one single variable? so you can check which case you have.

Comment: how can i utilise that? @SimoneRossaini using the if makes my code longer...

Comment: You do that by adding a variable named 'Answer' for example. Then you check with an IF statement if $answer is the same as $white.

Comment: @flochristos have you try my answer?

Comment: @simone,Thanks, i have but it's a bit legnthy.. i have to write that in five places...

Comment: if you use function it's just one the place and use function where you want.

Comment: have you test my code? @flochristos if all is ok can you acept my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For answer you question:

```
$variable='first / second ... '; // one variable
```

---

If you don't want use `IF` in the same page you can use function in another page:

```
function HowMuch($variable){
if($variable=='first'){
echo '      
      <option value="Explore" style="background: #fd7803; color: white;">Explore</option> 
      <option value="Prompt" style="background: #fdd303; color: white;">Prompt</option>
      <option value="Unaided" style="background: #58d95e; color: white;">Unaided</option>
      <option value="Mastered" style="background: #12c4f9; color: white;">Mastered</option> 
      <option value="Not Applicable" style="background: grey; color: black;">Not Applicable</option>';
}elseif($variable=='second '){
echo '  
      <option value="Prompt" style="background: #fdd303; color: white;">Prompt</option>
      <option value="Unaided" style="background: #58d95e; color: white;">Unaided</option>
      <option value="Mastered" style="background: #12c4f9; color: white;">Mastered</option> 
      <option value="Not Applicable" style="background: grey; color: black;">Not Applicable</option>';
 }
}
```

Now the page where select is place:

```
<select name="e1" id="year" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="" selected="selected" style="background: #0356e8;color: white;">-  -</option>
      HowMuch($variable); //variable contains first or second..
    </select>
```